# Disable Mega Menu panel while scrolling

Tags: html, css, wordpress, megamenu

I am using Max mega menu plugin for creating our mega menu by using full width layout. It's works properly.
When someone hover-over the menu tab it will open the mega menu panel, but when we on panel and try to scrolled down, the cursor goes down but we still on that panel.
So our menu bar panel already taking full width and in this case I want when some one is on the panel after hover-over the menu tab and when I scrolled down, it will get disabled and my website goes down as per cursor.

Our website link: http://indemortgage.staging.wpengine.com/

I am trying below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).scroll(function() { // check if scroll event happened
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) { // check if user scrolled more than 50 from top of the browser window
          $(".mega-sub-menu").css("display", "none"); 
        } 

      });
    });
```

But by using the above code it only works one time. when we go over the other tab, the new mega menu panel will not open.

Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `show` and `hide` with `else` statement like this:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
if( jQuery(document).scrollTop() > 50 ) {
jQuery('.mega-sub-menu').hide();
} else {
jQuery('.mega-sub-menu').show();
}
});
```

Comment: In this case it works well but when I scrolled down and hover-over it, it will not showing any mega menu panel. means it only work for > 50 scrolling. And I want it will disable on scrolling but it wil visible forever.

Comment: somebody help me with the same?